# Python 3.6.3 - login to oddsportal.com using selenium 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, authentication

This is my code for logging in to oddsportal.com:

```
from selenium import webdriver

login_url = "http://www.oddsportal.com/login/"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(login_url)

username = driver.find_element_by_name("login-username")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("login-password")
username.clear()
password.clear()
username.send_keys("my_username")
password.send_keys("my_password")

form = driver.find_element_by_name("login-submit")
form.click()
```

After that, the page just refreshes without any result. If I omit the last two lines (ie the submit part) and click "login" manually, everything is ok.

Can someone please help me? I am on Win10, Python 3.6.3 and using selenium 3.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *two buttons with the `login-submit` name and you are clicking the wrong one*.

Adjust your locator to target the desired form submit button:

```
submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#main button[name=login-submit]")
submit.click()
```

---

You can also submit the form using the [`submit()` method directly](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.submit):

```
username.submit()
```

The appropriate form submit button would then be located and "clicked" automatically.

Comment: Many thanks, the first method worked. However for some reason, username.submit() did not work. I have in fact tried all combinations before asking this question (username.submit(), username.click(), password.submit() and password.click()),but none worked. Anyway, thanks again.